# Create UserControl with CodeBehind at runtime in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, codedom

How to create a usercontrol and its codebehind from source file(s) at runtime and load into a panel?
I'm pretty sure using CodeDom could solve this, but not quite sure how to go about it. Can anyone provide a simplified example for this? Thanks in advance.

SAMPLE of script to complile

```
Option Infer On
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls

Namespace Evaluator

Public Class Evaluator
    Dim Project As New UserControl

    Dim Panel1 As New Panel
    Dim WithEvents Button1 As New Button
    Dim WithEvents TextBox1 As New TextBox

    Public Function GetProject(ByVal ParamArray expr() As Object) As UserControl

        'panel 1
        Panel1.Style.Add("background-color", "#D9E0E8")
        Panel1.Style.Add("padding-top", "5px")
        Panel1.Style.Add("margin-top", "5px")
        Panel1.Style.Add("width", "490px")
        Panel1.Style.Add("height", "30px")
        Project.Controls.Add(Panel1)

        'button 1
        Button1.ID = "Button1"
        Button1.Text = "Add"
        Button1.Width = 100
        AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf Button1_Click
        Panel1.Controls.Add(Button1)

        'textbox 1
        TextBox1.ID = "TextBox1"
        TextBox1.Width = 200
        TextBox1.Text = 0
        Panel1.Controls.Add(TextBox1)

        Return Project
    End Function

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox1.Text += 1
    End Sub

End Class

End Namespace
```

SAMPLE web page (Code Behind) to compile it

```
   Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim filePath = Server.MapPath("script.vb")
    Dim provider = VBCodeProvider.CreateProvider("VisualBasic")
    Dim opts = New CompilerParameters({"mscorlib.dll", "System.dll", "System.Web.dll", "Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll", "System.Data.dll", "System.Xml.dll", "System.Data.Linq.dll", "System.Core.dll", "System.Drawing.dll", "System.Web.Extensions.dll", "System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"})
    opts.CompilerOptions = "/t:library"
    opts.TreatWarningsAsErrors = False
    opts.GenerateExecutable = False
    opts.GenerateInMemory = True
    Dim cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(opts, New String() {filePath})

    'Check for compile errors
    If cr.Errors.Count > 0 Then
        HttpContext.Current.Session("_evaluator") = Nothing
        For Each err As CompilerError In cr.Errors
            Debug.Print(err.ErrorText, err.Line)
        Next
    Else
        'Create the Assembly and store in memory
        Dim evaluator As Object = Nothing
        evaluator = cr.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("Evaluator.Evaluator")
        HttpContext.Current.Session("_evaluator") = evaluator
        HttpContext.Current.Session("MyAssembly") = cr.CompiledAssembly.FullName
    End If

    Panel1.Controls.Clear()
    Call Evaluate()

End Sub

Public Sub Evaluate()

    Try
        'Invoke method
        Dim Evaluator As Object = CType(HttpContext.Current.Session("_evaluator"), Object)
        Dim objResult As Object = Evaluator.GetType.InvokeMember("GetProject", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod + Reflection.BindingFlags.Default, Nothing, Evaluator, Nothing)

        If Not objResult Is Nothing Then
            Panel1.Controls.Add(objResult)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to load via ascx file or class name?

Comment: I'm really not sure which way would be the best way yet

Comment: what is this source file you are talking about; (from where you create user control and code behind)?

Comment: I edited the question with some sample code. The problem is i have to InvokeMember on every post back. It would be nice to Load the usercontrol once until i need to change to a different one.